# Get SWT SashForm Sash in eclipse RCP e4

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

So I learned that if I call

```
sashForm.getChildren()
```

I'll have to call

```
sashForm.getParent().layout //or shell.layout()
```

if I would want the call to return the Sash(es).
Which is kind of logical because the Sash(es) are "build" only after the children are added.

I tried this in my RCP e4 Application but it did not work.
Anyone kown why ?

related bugreports with examplecode

[Bugreport1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436306),
[Bugreport2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436510)

Comment: It might just be the Layout set on the parent Composite. The Composite passed to an e4 part has the layout set to FillLayout.

Comment: I have thought of that, but this would mean that in the non-rcp version it also wouldn't work with a parent which has Fillayout.But is does (see the code example with bugreport 1) And .layout() does nothing when the Control has no layout,  but FillLayout is a layout. But thx for the idea :)

Comment: This seems to work fine on Mac OS X 10.9.3 with Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2